# *domain* does not designate permitted sender hosts

Tags: dns, spf

Right now, I'd like to use zoho mail for manual mailing from my domain and PHPMail from my server to handle automated messages.

Problem is, when my server sends out an email it hits spam filter. I get the following error:

> deemstars@server.deemstars.com does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=deemstars@server.deemstars.com

My txt record is the following (I Use Cloudflare):

> v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:207.244.68.190 a:server.deemstars.com include:zoho.com ?all

207.244.68.190 being my server IP. I also added multiple domains to the txt record to make sure it gets whitelisted. I also included zoho.com, which zohomail sends an email out just fine with no spam filter, and it doesn't get the "not permitted sender" error.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I've asked the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143698/error-with-emails-does-not-designate-permitted-sender Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So I think the problem is that your return path address has a domain of `server.deemstars.com` and your SPF record is defined only on the apex domain.  SPF does not check parent domains.

So add the following record to `server.deemstars.com`

```
v=spf1 ip4:207.244.68.190 a:server.deemstars.com include:zoho.com mx ptr ?all
```

and see if that addresses the issue.  I've also rearranged the SPF directives to move the cheaper to evaluate, more likely to match ones to the front.